# Getting all sister has_many records except the current record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

If a User `has_many :posts` and a Post `belongs_to :user`, and I have one particular Post saved in a variable called `@post`, what's the most succinct way I can get ALL posts which belong to the same user as `@post` EXCEPT `@post` itself?

The best I can come with is:

```
@post.user.posts.where('id NOT IN (?)', @post.id)
```

But this seems very verbose. (It seems redundant to have to repeat the word "post" three times.)

Is there a better or more succinct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a method which run this query

```
Post.where(user_id: @post.user_id).where.not(id: @post.id)
```

Comment: I've gone for this one as it returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` while the other ones return Arrays.

Comment: oops, missed that somehow. There you go.

Answer (score 2):

Since an active query result can be returned as an enumerable, you can use the enumerable method '-' instead :

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
[...]
  def other_posts
    user.posts - [self]
  end
[...]
end
```

Then you can call `@post.other_posts` !

Answer (score 0):

You can try like This

```
 post_result =  @post.user.posts - [@post]
```

Background: @post.user.posts  is the array in memory, as soon as you don't access it as a relation.[@post] is an array whith just the element, you want to delete (in memory).
@post.user.posts - [@post] does an array substraction.